# include<apis/api1/api.h> throws No such file or directory

Tags: c++, netbeans, directory, g++, cygwin

```
#include<apis/api1/api.h>
```

throws  No such file or directory
i even tried moving api.h and api.cc to the main project directory and using

```
#include<api.h>
```

does the same thing even though it is in the exact same directory that the other classes use 
i tried adding /apis/api1 to the compiler search path
 that just crashes the compiler can someone tell me what to type into the compilers compilation line

Comment: "throws" is the wrong term.

Comment: *i tried adding /apis/api1 to the compiler search path* - Considering you're using MinGW, that isn't even a valid full path. You might try reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename

Comment: actually no i thought it was using mingw im actually using  Cygwin ill edit the question

Comment: well it was "throwing" a big problem in my face so technically its the right term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <api.h>
```

is the way you include a *system* header. (That is, the header for a library installed on your system.) It does *not* search in the directory of the source file or in directories specified in `-I` command line arguments.

```
#include "api.h"
```

is the way you include your own headers. (But it will also search library header locations if it doesn't find the header locally.)