# #include <glad/glad.h>: No such file or directory (even though source and header are in the same directory)

Tags: c, opengl, cmake, header, opengl-extensions

I recently started converting a game engine I wrote in Java (using lwjgl) to C/C++. I am using Qt Creator and CMake on Fedora 25 (I'm pretty sure this doesn't affect anything) to link all the directories, files, etc. GLFW is installed on my system, but I decided to use the source version, rather than the included version. I am using glad for my extension loader, and configured it following the tutorial on the [GLFW website](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/context_guide.html#context_glext_auto). I haven't gotten past the "Hello World" test because when I include the `glad.h` file in my `main.c` file, I get an error:

`<glad/glad.h>: No such file or directory`

What is equally strange is that I get this same error in the `glad.c` file, the one that was created using glad's own generator. My `main.c` file looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Kick Ass Game Engine");
    return 0;
}
```

I have also tried using `"glad.h:` instead of `<glad/glad.h>` (I found that suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29019881/includeapis-api1-api-h-throws-no-such-file-or-directory)). This did work for my `main.c` file, but I still have the same issue with the `glad.c` file, even after I edited it to reflect `main.c`.

My project directory looks like this:

```
- KAGE/
  -> CMakeLists.txt
  -> glad.c
  -> glad.h
  -> main.c
  -> khplatform.h
-> KAGE/lib/
   -> glad
   -> glfw-3.2.1
```

As you can see, all of my `.c` and their header files are in one directory. The `lib` directory is where I keep glad and glfw. I just copied the files from the `lib/glad` directory to the main project one.

My `CMake` looks like this

```
project(KAGE)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})

set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

add_subdirectory(/home/brian/KAGE/lib/glfw-3.2.1)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(KAGE glfw)
```

I have tried searching around, but all of the issues people had where when trying to call libraries installed on the system. Mine are not installed. I have a separate directory (`lib`) where I keep everything I use. The only solution I found that came close to what I was looking for was the one about replacing `<glad/glad.h>` with `"glad.h"`. As I said earlier, this did not work. The tutorial on GLFW's website does not offer any other information or troubleshooting.

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake doesn't include current directory by default. For enable this behavior you need to set [CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR.html) variable:

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
```

After that for including the header your `glad.c` file may use

```
#include "glad.h"
```

Comment: This worked. I also had to change the `glad.c` file to use `#include "glad.h"` along with my `main.c`. Thank you. Do you have any idea as to why the `#include` didn't work before? It gave me the same error in the `glad.c` file, but had no issue with `#include  <GLFW/glfw3.h>`, even though they are both set up the same way in the project directory.

Comment: When you use `#include <glad/glad.h>` you ask compiler for find specified **relative path** in one of *include directories*. As none of your directory contains this relative path, compiler cannot find it. Also, include directories should be specified with `include_directories()` command in CMake. This is done by GLFW when you perform `add_subdirectory()` for build this library.

Answer (score 3):

Seems `glad.h` is not in a directory called `glad`, so including it via `glad/glad.h` is just never going to work!

If you on linux one trick is make a softlink to `.` called `glad` and then you can have `glad/glad/glad/glad/glad.h` if you want it.

Better solution is to install stuff properly so files end up at their expected paths...

Comment: Creating a `glad` directory did not work. I still have the same issue. I also installed glad according to the glad website. It is just used to generate the header files, and doesn't require any special install directories aside from the one `pip` uses. And since glfw has no issues with the way I set it up, I don't see how not having a glad directory is the issue. The glfw website also said to just take the files glad generates and place them in the project's root directory.

Answer (score 2):

Today I met the same problem and found this posting.
I use vcpkg to manage my pkg.
I can be sure that the path of the file is right，but it do not work.
And magically，when I delete #include <glad/glad.h> and reenter it，it works.

Comment: Are you sure, that when you "reentered" the include line, it was actually the same?

Answer (score 0):

If glad folder is in the project root directory, means:

```
KAGE
  glad
```

then the Cmakelist for glad:

```
# glad
set(GLAD_DIR "${LIB_DIR}glad")
add_library("glad" "${GLAD_DIR}/src/glad.c")
target_include_directories("glad" PRIVATE "${GLAD_DIR}/include")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "${GLAD_DIR}/include")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "glad" "${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")
```

if it's in a lib directory

```
KAGE
  lib
    glad
```

then change cmkaelist:
from `set(GLAD_DIR "${LIB_DIR}glad")` to `set(GLAD_DIR "${LIB_DIR}lib/glad")`