# Getting "fatal error: 'Math/v3d_optimization.h' file not found" with Cmake

Tags: c++, android-studio, opencv, cmake

I used cmake to build C++ source files in Android Studio.
I'm tying to import SSBA-4.0 library, but i'm new with Cmake

Full error:

```
C:\Users\usrname\AndroidProjects\myproject\app\src\main\cpp\SSBA-4.0\Math\v3d_optimization.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'Math/v3d_optimization.h' file not found
#include "Math/v3d_optimization.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

my **/CMakeList.txt** points to the library using `add_subdirectory(src/main/cpp/SSBA-4.0)`:

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# OpenCV IMPORT
include_directories(C:/OpenCV_android_sdk_3_0/sdk/native/jni/include)
add_library( lib-opencv SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib-opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java.so)


# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
             src/main/cpp/main.cpp
             src/main/cpp/Distance.h
             src/main/cpp/Distance.cpp
                src/main/cpp/Triangulation.cpp
                src/main/cpp/Triangulation.h
                src/main/cpp/FindCameraMatrices.cpp
                src/main/cpp/FindCameraMatrices.h
                src/main/cpp/MultiCameraDistance.cpp
                src/main/cpp/MultiCameraDistance.h
                src/main/cpp/IDistance.h
                src/main/cpp/MultiCameraPnP.cpp
                src/main/cpp/MultiCameraPnP.h
                src/main/cpp/Common.cpp
                src/main/cpp/Common.h
                src/main/cpp/IFeatureMatcher.h
                src/main/cpp/RichFeatureMatcher.cpp
                src/main/cpp/RichFeatureMatcher.h
                src/main/cpp/OFFeatureMatcher.cpp
                src/main/cpp/OFFeatureMatcher.h
                src/main/cpp/BundleAdjuster.cpp
                src/main/cpp/BundleAdjuster.h
                src/main/cpp/GPUSURFFeatureMatcher.cpp
                src/main/cpp/GPUSURFFeatureMatcher.h
                src/main/cpp/AbstractFeatureMatcher.cpp
                src/main/cpp/AbstractFeatureMatcher.h
                src/main/cpp/SfMUpdateListener.cpp
                src/main/cpp/SfMUpdateListener.h
             )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )

add_subdirectory(src/main/cpp/SSBA-4.0)
```

**src/main/cpp/SSBA-4.0/CMakeList.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(V3D)

set (V3D_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set (V3D_INCLUDE_DIRS ${V3D_DIR}/.)

include (Config/v3d_macros.cmake)

include (Config/local_config.cmake)

include_directories(${V3D_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${EXTRA_INC_DIRS})


source_group("Base" REGULAR_EXPRESSION Base/.*cpp|Base.*h)
set (BASE_SRC
    Base/v3d_exception.h
    Base/v3d_serialization.h
    Base/v3d_vrmlio.h
)
if (V3DLIB_ENABLE_SOCKETS)
    set (BASE_SRC ${BASE_SRC} Base/v3d_socket.h)
endif (V3DLIB_ENABLE_SOCKETS)

source_group("Math" REGULAR_EXPRESSION Math/.*cpp|Math.*h)
set (MATH_SRC
    Math/v3d_linear.h
    Math/v3d_linearbase.h
    Math/v3d_mathutilities.h
    Math/v3d_nonlinlsq.h
    Math/v3d_nonlinlsq.cpp
    Math/v3d_optimization.h
    Math/v3d_optimization.cpp
    Math/v3d_optimization_lm.cpp
)

source_group("Geometry" REGULAR_EXPRESSION Geometry/.*cpp|Geometry.*h)
set (GEOMETRY_SRC
    Geometry/v3d_cameramatrix.h
    Geometry/v3d_distortion.h
    Geometry/v3d_metricbundle.h
    Geometry/v3d_metricbundle.cpp
    Geometry/v3d_stereobundle.h
    Geometry/v3d_stereobundle.cpp
)

source_group("Dependencias" REGULAR_EXPRESSION Dependencias/.*cpp|Dependencias.*h)
set (DEPENDENCIAS_SRC
    Dependencias/colamd.h
    Dependencias/colamd.c
    Dependencias/UFConfig.h
    Dependencias/colamd_global.c
)

set (ALL_SRC
    ${BASE_SRC} ${MATH_SRC} ${GEOMETRY_SRC} ${GL_SRC} ${CUDA_SRC} ${DEPENDENCIAS_SRC}
)

add_library(V3D ${ALL_SRC})
add_subdirectory(Apps)
```

and the file path of **v3d_optimization.h** is **src/main/cpp/SSBA-4.0/Math/v3d_optimization.h**

this is the **v3d_optimization.cpp** header, where the error comes from:

```
#include "Math/v3d_optimization.h"

#if defined(V3DLIB_ENABLE_SUITESPARSE)
//# include "COLAMD/Include/colamd.h"
# include "Dependencias/colamd.h"
# if 0
extern "C"
{
//#  include "LDL/Include/ldl.h"
#  include "ldl.h"
}
# else
#  include "Math/v3d_ldl_private.h"
# endif
#endif

#define USE_BLOCK_REORDERING 1
//#define USE_MULTIPLICATIVE_UPDATE 1

#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

namespace V3D
{
```

*Thanks!*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#include <glad/glad.h>: No such file or directory (even though source and header are in the same directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430457/include-glad-glad-h-no-such-file-or-directory-even-though-source-and-header)

Comment: It´s different, because the error comes from inside os SSBA library, that runs perfect whe you compile it outside my project (SSBA-4.0/CMakeList.txt alone)... I didin't changed the sources. Updated my post with the v3d_optimization.cpp header.

Comment: "... that runs perfect whe you compile it outside my project (SSBA-4.0/CMakeList.txt alone)" - but in your case, you **don't use** `SSBA-4.0/CMakeList.txt`. Instead, you *manually* (with `add_library` call) build SSBA library from its source files. So it is you who should add appropriate include directories for compile these sources.

Comment: Worked moving the foolder src/main/cpp/SSBA-4.0 to src/main/SSBA-4.0
and importing into /CMakeList.txt using this lines:

set(SSBA_LIBRARY_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../SSBA-4.0/build" CACHE PATH "Directory to find SSBA libs")
link_directories(
   ${SSBA_LIBRARY_DIR}
 )
link_directories(${SSBA_LIBRARY_DIR})
include_directories(${SSBA_LIBRARY_DIR}/../)

Answer (score 0):

Worked moving the foolder **src/main/cpp/SSBA-4.0** to **src/main/SSBA-4.0** 
then importing into **/CMakeList.txt** using this lines:

```
set(SSBA_LIBRARY_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../SSBA-4.0/build" CACHE PATH "Directory to find SSBA libs") 
link_directories(${SSBA_LIBRARY_DIR}) 
include_directories(${SSBA_LIBRARY_DIR}/../)
```